# In ELF core file which section stores information on command invoked?

Tags: elf, coredump

```
$ hexdump -C <corefile>
000005a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  2e 2f 74 65 73 74 20 48  |........./test H|
000005b0  65 6c 6c 6f 20 57 6f 72  6c 64 20 00 00 00 00 00  |ello World .....|
```

The hexdump shows string like "./test Hello World"

How to read command invoked string from ELF core file?

Answer (score 2):

The note section of the core file has 'prpsinfo' which has executable name & arguments info.

```
readelf --notes /b/syrajendra/core.test.25963.1518497907

Notes at offset 0x000003f8 with length 0x00000614:
  Owner                 Data size       Description
  CORE                 0x00000150       NT_PRSTATUS (prstatus structure)
  CORE                 0x00000088       NT_PRPSINFO (prpsinfo structure)
  CORE                 0x00000080       Unknown note type: (0x53494749)
  CORE                 0x00000130       NT_AUXV (auxiliary vector)
```

"prpsinfo" structure is defined in "/usr/include/linux/elfcore.h" file.

Comment: Note that `sizeof(elf_prpsinfo.pr_psargs) == ELF_PRARGSZ == 80`, so only the first 80 characters of the command line are saved.